# readdir while loop not executing

Tags: php

I currently have a while loop that should read a given directory and then populate a select element with these files. Currently the select element remains empty but if i remove the while loop it will then display the first option. This code works fine on my local machine and this error is only produced on the remote server. can anyone else see if there's something i might be missing?

The code:

```
$path="files/Sales 101/module 1/";
$current_dir = $path;
$dir = opendir($current_dir);
while($file=readdir($dir)){
    $filepath = $current_dir.$file;    
    if($file == "." or $file == "..")
    {
        echo " ";
    }
    else
    {    
        echo "<option value='$filepath'>$file</option>";
    }             
}
```

Comment: check that you are having same folder structure on both the server.

Comment: Exactly that. Does the directory specified in `$path` actually contain files on the server?

Comment: Yes, as far as i can see the folder structure is the same on both servers. both in structure and the files contained there

Comment: Please just read the First example in the manual for [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) You would be amazed what you can get from the manual

Comment: i have read the example in the manual and adjusted the code accordingly, however, this just causes the page to load endlessly(only on the remote server. everything still works locally)

Comment: Turns out this was happening because in my $path variable the letter 'm' in 'module 1' was not upper case. Thanks for all the speedy responses.

Answer (score 1):

according to the php manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) you should use

```
while(false !== $dir && ($file=readdir($dir))){...
```

because if it in fact the opendir returns false you'd have an inifinite loop.
Eventually checking the type of $dir may confirm this.

Answer (score -1):

May I you local and live server OS? Whether it is linux or windows?

If Linux:

It must be a **'/'** slash error. You should give the **'\'** for path of the directory. 
EG: `$path="files\Sales 101\module 1\";`

If Windows:

try to replace a spaces of path.

EG: `$path="files/Sales_101/module_1/";`

Comment: PHP sorts this out internally. You should use the unix `/` regardless of the target OS

Comment: live server is linux. replacing '/' with '\' gives the same result.